# .Net Web API Core Upgrade from 1.1 to 2.0 slower on AWS Lambda

Tags: lambda, .net-core

Just migrated a .Net Web API Core from 1.1 to 2.0 on AWS Lambda and the execution time used to be 1.5s and is know 3s.

Why is that if no infrastructure was modified?

Answer (score -1):

If you are able, consider moving your project to TypeScript/NodeJs, as it wil consistently load within a few 100s of milliseconds.